# Value Error from callbacks in sentdex tutorial

Tags: python, keras, callback, recurrent-neural-network, valueerror

I've gotten to the end of Sentdex's tutorial series about RNN and crypto currency. For the life of me I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. My best guess is that there is something wrong with how I'm saving the data but no matter what I try I keep getting the same "ValueError" on my line "callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint]. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from sklearn import preprocessing
from collections import deque
import random
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint


SEQ_LEN = 60
FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT = 3
RATIO_TO_PREDICT = "LTC-USD"
EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 64
NAME = f"{RATIO_TO_PREDICT}-{SEQ_LEN}-SEQ-{FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT}-PRED-{int(time.time())}"

def classify(current, future):
    if float(future) > float(current):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
def preprocess_df(df):
    df = df.drop('future', 1)
    
    for col in df.columns:
        if col != "target":
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change()
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)
            
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    
    sequential_data = []
    prev_days = deque(maxlen=SEQ_LEN)
    
    for i in df.values:
        prev_days.append([n for n in i[:-1]])
        if len(prev_days) == SEQ_LEN:
            sequential_data.append([np.array(prev_days), i[-1]])
            
    random.shuffle(sequential_data)
    
    buys = []
    sells = []
    
    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        if target == 0:
            sells.append([seq, target])
        elif target == 1:
            buys.append([seq, target])
            
    random.shuffle(buys)
    random.shuffle(sells)
    
    lower = min(len(buys), len(sells))
    
    buys = buys[:lower]
    sells = sells[:lower]
    
    sequential_data = buys+sells
    random.shuffle(sequential_data)
    
    X = []
    y = []
    
    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        X.append(seq)
        y.append(target)
    return np.array(X), y

main_df = pd.DataFrame()

ratios = ["BTC-USD", "LTC-USD", "BCH-USD", "ETH-USD"]
for ratio in ratios:

    ratio = ratio.split('.csv')[0]
    print(ratio)
    dataset = f'C:/crypto_data/{ratio}.csv'  # get the full path to the file.
    df = pd.read_csv(dataset, names=['time', 'low', 'high', 'open', 'close', 'volume'])

    df.rename(columns={"close":f"{ratio}_close", "volume":f"{ratio}_volume"}, inplace=True)

    df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
    df = df[[f"{ratio}_close", f"{ratio}_volume"]]

    if len(main_df) == 0:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df)
        
main_df['future'] = main_df[f'{RATIO_TO_PREDICT}_close'].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT)
main_df['target'] = list(map(classify, main_df[f'{RATIO_TO_PREDICT}_close'], main_df['future']))

main_df.dropna(inplace=True)

times = sorted(main_df.index.values)
last_5pct = sorted(main_df.index.values)[-int(0.05*len(times))]

validation_main_df = main_df[(main_df.index >= last_5pct)]
main_df = main_df[(main_df.index < last_5pct)]

train_x, train_y = preprocess_df(main_df)
validation_x, validation_y = preprocess_df(validation_main_df)

print(f"train data: {len(train_x)} validation: {len(validation_x)}")
print(f"Dont buys: {train_y.count(0)}, buys: {train_y.count(1)}")
print(f"VALIDATION Dont buys: {validation_y.count(0)}, buys: {validation_y.count(1)}")

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="C:/logs/{}".format(NAME))

filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.3f}"  # unique file name that will include the epoch and the validation acc for that epoch
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("C:/models/{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')) # saves only the best ones

history = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
)

model.save("C:/models/{}".format(NAME))
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-2583585ee356> in <module>
    152     epochs=EPOCHS,
    153     validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
--> 154     callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
    155 )
    156 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    233           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    234           workers=workers,
--> 235           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    236 
    237       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, steps_per_epoch, validation_split, validation_data, validation_steps, shuffle, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    531                      'at same time.')
    532 
--> 533   adapter_cls = data_adapter.select_data_adapter(x, y)
    534 
    535   # Handle validation_split, we want to split the data and get the training

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    996         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    997         "input: {}, {}".format(
--> 998             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
    999   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
   1000     raise RuntimeError(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.float64'>"})
```

Comment: first you could use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables used in `callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint]` . It seems you have `numpy.ndarray` but it may need different type of data. OR maybe it need newer (or older) version of `tensorflow`. You could add in question (not in comment)  link for this tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I found mentioned [sendtex tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/crypto-rnn-model-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/?completed=/balancing-rnn-data-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/) and there is no information how old is this tutorial - but there is video which you can open on YouTube and it shows it is `2 years old` tutorial. Maybe 2 years ago this code worked in older version of tensorflow.

---

Error shows problem with data type

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: 
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.float64'>"})
```

for line

```
--> 154     callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
```

which is part of function `model.fit()`

So I get all variables in `model.fit()` and check `type`

```
print('tensorboard:', type(tensorboard))
print('checkpoint:',  type(checkpoint))

print('train_x:',      type(train_x))
print('train_y:',      type(train_y))
print('validation_x:', type(validation_x))
print('validation_y:', type(validation_y))
```

which gives

```
tensorboard: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard'>
checkpoint: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint'>

train_x: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
train_y: <class 'list'>
validation_x: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
validation_y: <class 'list'>
```

and you can see mentioned in error `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` for `train_x`, `validation_x` and `<class 'list'>` for `train_y`, `validation_y`

Digging on internet I found in Tensorflow tutorial [Training and evaluation with the built-in methods](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) two lines before `model.fit()`

```
y_train = y_train.astype("float32")
y_test = y_test.astype("float32")
```

which mean `y` values have to be `numpy.array` but in your code `train_y` is a normal `list`

Finally code works when `model.fit()` gets `np.array(train_y)` instead of `train_y`

```
history = model.fit(
    train_x, 
    
    np.array(train_y), # <--- instead of `train_y`

    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
)
```